# calulation of data between columns based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osAyx.jpg)    date    engine_meter   workflow_indicator  Result

```
2-Mar-15    42           SS
2-Mar-15    58           ES
3-Mar-15    58           SS
3-Mar-15   1028         ES   
4-Mar-15   1028         SS
4-Mar-15    1104    EV                     76
4-Mar-15     1104   EV                     76
4-Mar-15    1104    EV                     76
4-Mar-15    2681    EV                    1653
4-Mar-15    2681    ES
5-Mar-15    2681    SS
5-Mar-15    2682    EV                      1
5-Mar-15    2682    EV                      1
5-Mar-15    2682    EV                      1
5-Mar-15    2704    EV                      23
5-Mar-15    2704    EV                      23
5-Mar-15    4287    ES
```

Three columns with Date, engine meter and Workflow.
In workflow, you can see SS,EV and ES

Each date will have SS and ES.
Can you please help me out to find out the difference of engine meter between the each EV and SS of each day.

I want in F column ,if D7,D8,D9,D10 is less than X% of B11, than the value 1 should return otherwise it should return 0.Similar way for rest of the rows
I am getting error. can you please help me out.

Comment: You can do this yourself with simple subtraction formula on row of second date - please give something  a try and report back with you information that you tried

Comment: What do SS, ES and EV mean? I don't understand your question.

Comment: SS means start of shift, EV means Issues and ES means End of shift.i have bunch of data of around 1 year and i need to calculate the difference of engine meter between SS and EV of each date

Comment: Please put in your example what your desired outcome would be.

Comment: 4-Mar-15 1104    EV    76
4-Mar-15 1104    EV    76
4-Mar-15 1104    EV    76
4-Mar-15 2681  EV  1653
4-Mar-15 2681  ES 
5-Mar-15 2681  SS 
5-Mar-15 2682  EV 1
5-Mar-15 2682  EV 1
5-Mar-15 2682  EV 1
5-Mar-15 2704  EV 23
5-Mar-15 2704  EV 23
If you see n 2nd and 3rd march no EV so, i don't want the data there.But in 4th and 5th i am having EV. SO each meter count of EV of 5th march should get subtracted from SS of 5th march

Comment: Not in a comment, [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37845142/edit) your original question.  It is hard to understand in the comment.

Comment: @Scott I have updated the question with required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula in D2:

```
=IF(C2="EV",B2-INDEX($B$1:B2,MATCH(2,IF($C$1:C2="SS",1))),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula automatically.

Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: That really helps.Thanks alot for your time and help.have great day.

Comment: @javed this only works if it is sorted and every day starts with "SS".

Comment: ,yes in my case it would work great since my day starts with SS only.Thanks 4 your advice.

Comment: ,can you please check the link [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/osAyx.jpg .Actually i want to compare the data between D and B rows,if the condition satisfies, it should return 1, else 0.For eg, if D7,D8,D9,D10 is less than 80% of B11, value in F7,F8,F9,F10 should be 1 else 0.

Comment: That is a new question that should have it's own post.

Comment: Hi Scott, I was able to get the output .Anyways thanks for your help.